# Why this precondition will be fail,I don't understand well

Tags: dafny

```
datatype message = Nil | Aenc(aencMsg:message,aencKey:message) | Senc(m1:message,m2:message) | K(r1:role,r2:role) | Pk(r:role) | Sk(r:role) | Str(r:role) | Var(n:role) | Concat(array<message>)
type channel = array<message>
method ReceiveMsgFromChannel(c:channel) returns (m:message)
    requires c.Length > 0 
    requires c[0] != Nil
    ensures  c[0] == Nil
    // requires verify(c)
    modifies c
{
    m:=c[0];
    c[0]:=Nil;
}
method AliceSendMsg_1(c:channel)
    requires c.Length > 0
    modifies c
{
    var aencMsg:=new message[2];
    aencMsg[0]:=Var("Na");
    aencMsg[1]:=Str("A");
    var m :=Aenc(Concat(aencMsg),Pk("B"));
    c[0] :=m;
    assert m.aencKey == Pk("B");
}
method Test(ch1:channel)
    requires ch1.Length>0
    requires forall i:int :: 0<=i<ch1.Length ==> ch1[i]==Nil
    modifies ch1
 {
    AliceSendMsg_1(ch1);
    var m1:=ReceiveMsgFromChannel(ch1);
}
```

This is part of my code.I try to define two entities in protocol，One sends message,another receives message.And there AliceSendMsg_1 represent Alice sends the msg of aenc not Nil.Then Bob  receives the Msg from Channel.But the message can not be Nil.Why the precondtion fails.Any help in getting this to verify is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The body of `Test` first executes,

```
AliceSendMsg_1(ch1);
```

Furthermore, `AliceSendMsg_1` is marked with `modifies ch1` but does not give any postcondition. Therefore, when Dafny reasons about the method `Test`, it knows absolutely nothing about the contents of `ch1` after the call to `AliceSendMsg_1`. Remember that when Dafny is verifying `Test`, it does not look into the body of `AliceSendMsg_1`. All it knows about `AliceSendMsg_1` is whatever is in the signature of that method.

You can fix this by simply adding the property you need to the signature of `AliceSendMsg_1`.

```
method AliceSendMsg_1(c:channel)
    requires c.Length > 0 
    ensures c[0] != Nil  // add this line
    modifies c
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I still have some question abot nest datetype.Is it convient to consult with you via email